# Regex for anything between []

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need to find the regex for []

For eg, if the string is - Hi [Stack], Here is my [Tag] which i need to [Find].

It should return 
Stack, Tag, Find

Comment: Can there be nested matches: `foo [bar[baz]] done` where you want to grab `bar[baz]`? Or perhaps `foo [bar\\]baz] done` where you want to grab `bar]baz`? Can there be new line(s) between `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Pretty simple, you just need to (1) escape the brackets with backslashes, and (2) use `(.*?)` to capture the contents.

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

The parentheses are a capturing group, they capture their contents for later use. The question mark after `.*` makes the matching non-greedy. This means it will match the shortest match possible, rather than the longest one. The difference between greedy and non-greedy comes up when you have multiple matches in a line:

```
Hi [Stack], Here is my [Tag] which i need to [Find].
   ^______________________________________________^
```

A greedy match will find the longest string possible between two sets of square brackets. That's not right. A non-greedy match will find the shortest:

```
Hi [Stack], Here is my [Tag] which i need to [Find].
   ^_____^
```

Anyways, the code will end up [looking like](http://ideone.com/NSIYu):

```
string regex = @"\[(.*?)\]";
string text  = "Hi [Stack], Here is my [Tag] which i need to [Find].";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, regex))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: @henning Yes, the equivalent Python code has the [same output](https://www.online-python.com/uO4ytT5qLN).

Comment: "Pretty simple" not so much. Just put an ASCII character in your string see it yourself. For example, nothing will happen to this string. `"Hi [St" + (char) 10 +"ack]"`

Comment: @Farid Of course that won't work. `(char) 10` is a `\n` newline character. It has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: You are right it is a newline, though the question asks specifically "anything between". I think `\[(?s)(.*)\]` would be more accurate, at least, for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

```
\[([\w]+?)\]
```

should work. You might have to change the matching group if you need to include special chars as well.

Comment: This works a bit more nicely than the currently tagged answer because it has better control over things like this: "Test [test] [ test [test]" The tagged answer will include the stray [ in the match, whereas this regex will not.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what environment you mean:

```
\[([^\]]+)]
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET syntax, taking care of multiple embedded brackets:

`\[ ( (?: \\. | (?<OPEN> \[) | (?<-OPEN> \]) | [^\]] )*? (?(OPEN)(?!)) ) \]`

This counts the number of opened `[` sections in `OPEN` and only succeeds if `OPEN` is 0 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and discovered that this also does the trick.

```
\[\w{1,}\]
```

The **\w** means ***Metacharacter***. This will match 1 or more word characters.

Using **n{X,}** quantifier matches any string where you can obtain different amounts. With the second number left out on purpose, the expression means 1 or more characters to match.