# Regex matches not working

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I am doing a very simple task: parsing a website, looking for

```
<tbody>this is what important for me</tbody>`
```

and returning but I just cannot make it work. When I do:

```
Regex.Matches(webData, @"<tbody>(.*?)</tbody>")
```

it gives me no results. This, however, gives me 2 results:

```
Regex.Matches(webData, @"tbody")
```

but again, this

```
Regex.Matches(webData, @"tbody(.*?)tbody")
```

gives me nothing (so I assume escaping is not the problem). I found about `(.*?)` at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677255/regex-for-anything-between) and I assumed it will be pretty easy to use, but I just cannot work it out.

Comment: Please update your title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: You need to escape some symbols. Try `"\<tbody\>(.*?)\<\/tbody\>"` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you should see: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1465011)

Comment: What if I have `<tbody class="">regex failz</tbody>`? NEVER USE REGEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regex` for parsing html is not recommended

`regex` is used for regularly occurring patterns.`html` is not regular with it's format(except `xhtml`).For example `html` files are valid even if you **don't** have a `closing tag`!This could break your code.

Use an html parser like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can use this code to retrieve all tbody's content using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

var tbodyList= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tBody")
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();
```

`tbodyList` contains all `tbody` values in the entire document!

Answer (score 2):

To parse a web page use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
string html = "<tbody>this is what important for me</tbody>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tbody").First().InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend HtmlAgilityPack too.

You can use also XPath (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

On the I4V example:

```
var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody").InnerText;
```